# Ruby. Range:Each change value

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a siple script, that calculates fibonacci numbers in a loop:

```
def fib(v)
 return v if v < 2
 (fib(v-2) + fib(v-1))
end

[0..15].each do |i|
  puts "#{fib(i-1)} "
end
```

But this code fails because i-1 cannot be executed, as i has type Range. What should I do with it? I know, there are many other ways to calculate fibonacci numbers, but I need this code to work, not to rewrite it.

Comment: It makes sense to use a range as the receiver, as @Peereboom suggests, but if you want to create an array that contains the values in a range, you need to convert a range to an array: `a = *(1..15)` or `a = (1..15).to_a`, `=> [1,2,3,..,15]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue:  `[]` is the syntax for creating an array. So `[0..15]` creates an array with one element. That one element is the `Range`, `0..15`.  Range itself is an enumerable, so you can:

```
(0..15).each do |i|
  puts fibonacci(i - 1)
end
```

- As a side note, using interpolating strings in unnecessary when you have just 1 element to print.